# Getting an error in a MERN app: Can't resolve 'react-quill/lib/toolbar'

Tags: javascript, editor, toolbar, mern, quill

I am building a clone of Stack Overflow using React for an assignment. But I am getting the following error holding me from completion:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-quill/lib/toolbar'.

Here is a code snippet:

```
import Editor from "react-quill/lib/toolbar";

import Editor from "react-quill/api/toolbar";

Editor.modules = {
    syntax: false,
    toolbar: toolbarOptions,
    clipboard: {
      // toggle to add extra line breaks when pasting HTML:
      matchVisual: false,
    },
  };
  /*
   * Quill editor formats
   * See https://quilljs.com/docs/formats/
   */
  Editor.formats = [
    "header",
    "font",
    "size",
    "bold",
    "italic",
    "underline",
    "strike",
    "blockquote",
    "list",
    "bullet",
    "indent",
    "link",
    "image",
    "video",
  ];
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using version 2 of `react-quill`? It doesn't have a `react-quill/lib/toolbar.js` file, so it's obvious that this error occurs.